# Customizing apache directory listing

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, website, file-server, directory-listing

I have a server with Apache directory listing.  I have styled it a little bit, and tried owncloud as well, but the solution I found best was a little themed Apache directory listing. However, I would like to add a search bar and an upload button, and if it's not too hard, a file delete button. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If your only planning to list 1 directory, I would download and use a file based management service. There are a lot of web based scripts out there. Ones as simple as a index.php which works.

Comment: hmmm, whats a file based management service? My directory listing works as a dropbox server, as of now i upload with sftp, which is unavailible at schools, thats one of the reasons i wanted a upload button, i list a directory with many files and folders in it